# Angular.js copy values in row of textbox array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, input, textbox

I have a row of input text boxes. I want to bring in the below functionality.

a) If I enter a value in the first input, the value should automatically copied/updated to next all text box(s). i.e to 2 till 10

b) Suppose I enter/update a value in 5th box, the value must be copied/updated automatically to 6, 7,8,9,10 but not to 4,3,2,1.

how & what is the easiest way to achieve this in angular.js?

[Sample Row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYH3e.png)

Comment: Please show the code you have tried!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the value in ngChange and update the subsequent input values. Example below.

```js
angular
  .module('exampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ExampleController);

function ExampleController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.inputValues = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4]
  ];
  vm.updateSubsequentInputs = function(idx, row, value) {
    for (var i = idx; i < row.length; i++) {
      row[i] = value;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='exampleApp'>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="inputRow in vm.inputValues">
      <td ng-repeat="inputValue in inputRow track by $index">
        <input ng-model="inputValue" ng-change="vm.updateSubsequentInputs($index, inputRow, inputValue)">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. Perfectly works. Updating the array in a for loop works if it is single row. I have multiple rows(say around 40) with the same function. So the value should get updated only on that particular row and not all. I'm trying to change the logic, but would appreciate if you can give me some idea on it.

Comment: See the updated example. The idea is the same it just uses multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

Its working , try it

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) { 
  $scope.name = 'World'; 
  
  $scope.myNumbers = [ {value: 1,index: 1}, {value: 2,index: 2}, {value: 3,index: 3}, {value: 4,index: 4}, {value: 5,index: 5}, {value: 6,index: 6}, {value: 7,index: 7}, {value: 8,index: 8} ];
  
 
  
$scope.testFn=function(val,ind){ 
  
     for (var i in $scope.myNumbers) {
       
     if ($scope.myNumbers[i].index > ind) {
      
        $scope.myNumbers[i].value = val; 
     }
   }
     
}
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

  <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    
    <div ng-repeat="num in myNumbers">
  <input type="text" ng-model="num.value" ng-change="testFn(num.value,num.index)">
    </div>
    
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a *cleaner* version:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.values = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
      $scope.change = function(index) {
        $scope.values = $scope.values.slice(0, index).concat(Array($scope.values.length - index).fill($scope.values[index]));
      }
    });
})();
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="value in values track by $index">
        <input type="text" size="1" ng-model="values[$index]" ng-change="change($index)">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```